# how to configure google backup and sync on Mac to upload photos to google cloud?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-photos

this mac App is very confusing regarding selecting the proper options.

1. I have several folders on my mac drive and an attached usb drive with pics and vids
2. I want the G BU&S app to upload these photos to my google photos library in their cloud
3. I ALSO want the app to sync my local mac folder /Google Drive  with my cloud google drive
4. these are 2 different actions but i think the G BU&S app can do both of them but which checkboxes do i need
5. part of my confusion is a message I get asking Continue Merge? (129k items will sync). Im afaid to check yes because i dont know what it is referring to

Comment: I think https://superuser.com/ is probably the best place for this type of question as its not about coding.

Comment: ok... i will post there. thanks